# How does one await the completion of a task or suspend a method in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs, zurb-joyride

I am using a third party library that renders some UI.  The api has a callback function so one can run necessary code before invoking the next UI change in the third party library.  In my scenario, I perform a user action (clicking a button), the third party library starts processing the action, the call back method is invoked, I fire off an action that my store is listening to which then updates my own UI.

The problem I am running is that the third party library is dependent on my UI updating before it updates its own UI. In the callback method where after I fire off my action, the call back method ends before my store has completed the code in it's event handler.  I would like my action to fire in the callback method and for the callback method to wait until my own UI update has finished before continuing.

Example Scenario Code:

**Action**

```
var Actions = Reflux.createActions([
    "updateUI"
]);
```

**Store**

```
class Store extends Reflux.Store {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.listenables = Actions;
    }

    onUpdateUI(){
        //Update the UI
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
class Component extends Reflux.Component{

    handleCallback(){
        Action.updateUI();
        // Wait until UI has updated or wait x amount of time before 
        //returning.
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ThirdPartyComponent callback = {this.handleCallback} />
        );
    }
}
```

I have looked at several different methods of handling this (Promises, async/await, creating a callback for the action) and each have their draw backs and none gave examples following the unidirectional flow that Reflux offers.  I am curious if there is a proper way of handling this type of scenario.

Comment: The only way I could see this working is if the 3rd party library passed a callback function to your `handleCallback` function. Is there any chance you can share which 3rd party library you're using?

Comment: @bmceldowney sure thing!  I am using React Joyride https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride

Comment: I've never used joyride but maybe you can do something like setting `run` to false at the beginning of your callback and then set it to true once your UI is updated. That's about all I can think of in this situation.

Comment: @bmceldowney thanks for the idea!  Unfortunately, the callback will finish before I am able to update `run`.  So I am left with the same result.